# Can paypal recurring payment trial period have 0 amount?

Tags: paypal, payment, paypal-subscriptions

I have implemented paypal recurring payment without any trial period.

Now I need to be able have 1 month full free subscription, is that possible with trial period.
Can a trial amount for recurring payment be zero ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the PROFILESTARTDATE to start the recurring payments after the trial period.

Comment: well, Robert ! Actually when payment is done then I enable the account, in case of starting profile after trial period I will not get the IPN and thus the subscription will be pending no my site. What I need is have the trial period with zero amount.

Comment: You could also set TRIALAMT to 0.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was talking about, now I set TRIALAMT to 0 , would I get IPN when payment is done (0 can't be paid but, on the payment time, would I get IPN)?

Say I have 10 trial periods of TrialAmt = 0 , and billing frequency is set every 1Day. Now would I get IPN till 10 days since the profile is started? because the trial amount is 0, so nothing will be paid.

Comment: Yes; you'll get a recurring_payment_profile created txn_type IPN upon profile creation, and a recurring_payment txn_type IPN when the payment has gone through after 10 days (and recurring_payment_skipped if it hasn't). You'll receive this IPN whenever a recurring payment has gone through. See also https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_IPNandPDTVariables#id08CTB0S055Z